# Seo panel Google API verification fails

Tags: api-authorization

I've setup Seo Panel ( https://www.seopanel.org/) several times already on different websites and it's always worked ok.

I recently migrated to a new server and when setting up Seo Panel the API verify connection fails and no data is collected.
The 'verify connection' > Fail is instant, this leads me to believe the I.P of the server is blocked somewhere.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Thanks
Alec

Comment: Can you share some more information about what is the configuration of your new server, steps followed etc. ?

Comment: The server is  Ubuntu 18.04 with a typical setup for hosting.  The panel is installed from softaculous with guidance here https://www.seopanel.org/docs/user_guide/settings.html#google-api-key  for settings  --  I get a few details so Oauth2 seems to work but not API